# How to edit this code to get the image instead of title?

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

Some one please help me to figure this out.
I am working with PHPSound script and learning myself. I need some help.

How to edit this code to get the track image instead of title?

```
// Get the current played song name
if ($('#song-name'+id).html().length > 25) {
    var songName = $('#song-name'+id).html().substr(0, 25)+'...';
} else {
    var songName = $('#song-name'+id).html();
}

$('#sw-song-name').html(songName);
```

and this is in classes.php

```
class player {
public $db;
public $url;
public $l_per_post;
public $title;

function getEmbed($id) {
    global $LNG;
    $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users`, `tracks` WHERE `tracks`.`id` = '%s' AND `tracks`.`uid` = `users`.`idu` AND `tracks`.`public` = 1 AND `users`.`private` != 1", $this->db->real_escape_string($id)));

    // Set the result into an array
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    if($query->num_rows) {
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $tags = explode(',', $row['tag']);
            $row['tag'] = $tags[0];
            $track = '<div id="track'.$row['id'].'" class="embed-container">
                <div class="song-art"><a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=track&id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$this->url.'/thumb.php?src='.$row['art'].'&t=m&w=112&h=112" id="song-art'.$row['id'].'" /></a></div>
                <div class="song-top">
                    <div class="embed-powered-by">
                        <a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=track&id='.$row['id'].'" id="song-url'.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$this->title.'</a>
                    </div>
                    <div data-track-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-track-id="'.$row['id'].'" id="play'.$row['id'].'" class="track song-play-btn">
                    </div>
                    <div class="song-titles">
                        <div class="song-author"><a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$row['username'].'" target="_blank">'.realName($row['username'], $row['first_name'], $row['last_name']).'</a></div>
                        <div class="song-tag">
                            <a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=explore&filter='.$row['tag'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['tag'].'</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="song-title">
                            <a href="'.$this->url.'/index.php?a=track&id='.$row['id'].'" id="song-url'.$row['id'].'" target="_blank"><div id="song-name'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</div></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="player-controls">
                    <div id="song-controls'.$row['id'].'">
                        <div id="jp_container_123" class="jp-audio">
                            <div class="jp-type-single">
                                    <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                                        <div class="jp-progress">
                                            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="track-actions-container">
                    <div class="track-actions"><div class="track-actions-content" id="track-action'.$row['id'].'">'.$this->embedStats($row['id']).'</div></div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
    } else {
        return '<div style="width: 100%; background: url('.$this->url.'/uploads/media/default.png) top center no-repeat #b6b6b6; height: 140px;" class="embed-error"><div class="embed-error-title"><a href="'.$this->url.'" target="_blank">'.$this->title.'</a></div><div class="embed-error-desc"><a href="'.$this->url.'" target="_blank">'.$LNG['embed_error'].'</a></div></div>';
    }
    return $track;
}
```

Comment: by track image, are you talking about the url? `$('#song-art'+id).attr('src');`.

Comment: Not just the url, I want to display the current played song-art.  if you visit this, play a song you see that the playing song's title is showing in player. I want to show the song's thumb > http://phpsound.com/demo/index.php?a=explore

Answer (score 0):

In wrapper.html find

```
$('#sw-song-name').html(songName);
```

and after that

simply paste these line of codes.

```
var songartImg = ''+ $('#song-art'+id).attr("src") +'';
$('#topbar-song-art').attr("src", songartImg);
```

and where you wanted to show you picture for the current playing song near the player simply add

```
<img src="http://yourdomain.com/uploads/media/default.png" width="40" height="40" id="topbar-song-art" />
```